# AFNetworking how to check if upload operation has finished or failed

Tags: objective-c, upload, notifications, afnetworking

How can I check if AFNetworking has finished the upload of a file? And how I could check if there were some problems?

this is my code:

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server"]];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:[fieldName text] forKey:@"name"];
[parameters setObject:[fieldSurname text] forKey:@"surname"];

NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:[[AttachedFile sharedAttachedFile]dataToSend] mimeType:@"image/jpeg" name:@"attach"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest] autorelease]; 
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

which method (and delegate) I should implement?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperation HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest
                                                success:(void (^)(id object))success 
                                                failure:(void (^)(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure];
```

instead of

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest] autorelease];
```

When your file is completely upload the success block is called. If there's a problem the failure block is called.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest** is deprecated, you better use **setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure** on a AFHTTPRequestOperation instance

Check mattt's answer at [AFNetworking Uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234186/afnetworking-uploading-a-file)