# AFNetworking Uploading a file

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

Does any one have a full implementation of uploading a file using AFNetworking. I have found some code on the internet but it is incomplete. The code I have found is here:

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.client.server.com"]];


NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:[fieldName text] forKey:@"field01_nome"];
[parameters setObject:[fieldSurname text] forKey:@"field02_cognome"];



NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/Contents/mail/sendToForm.jsp" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:myNSDataToSend mimeType:@"image/jpeg" name:@"alleagto"];
}];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPRequestOperation HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest success:^(id object) {
    NSLog(@"Success");

} failure:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail");

}];


[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];

queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

I get errors on the following lines:

```
 [formData appendPartWithFileData:myNSDataToSend mimeType:@"image/jpeg" name:@"alleagto"];
```

At the myNSDataToSend.

And here:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPRequestOperation HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest success:^(id object) {
    NSLog(@"Success");

} failure:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail");

}];
```

The error is:

Class method '+HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure' not found(return type defaults to 'id')

Any help on this and uploading with AFNetworks would be amazing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, make sure you have the latest version of AFNetworking downloaded.

`AFHTTPRequestOperation +HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` was removed a few versions back. Instead, you can do `[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:...]` and then set the `completionBlock` with either the straight property accessor (`operation.completionBlock = ^{...}`), or with `-setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:`. Keep in mind that completion blocks execute after the request has finished downloading.

As for the multipart form block, `-appendWithFileData:mimeType:name` was also removed a while back. The method you want is `-appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:`.

Make those two changes and everything should work.

Comment: Hmm, I am still (a) finding that method in AFHTTPClient.m and (b) getting a compile error. Except my error says "Declaration of anonymous class must be a definition." Where can I look to fix this?

Comment: @mattt, can I change content-type from `multipart/form-data;` to `image/jpeg` while uploading image using `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` method? Need ur help!

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek No. You're sending a multipart form with a JPEG part, not a JPEG by itself.

Comment: @mattt face the same question, looking for some function allow me to post one file.