# AFNetworking Error - 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)' - when uploading audio file

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, cloudinary

I am attempting to use `AFNetworking` to upload an audio file to Cloudinary through a POST call. I have been using `AFNetworking` to send POST calls to my own server with ease but this is the first time I have tried sending an `NSData` object through AFNetworking which is where I think the problem lies and am not exactly sure how I need to adjust the call to get it to work.

***My Code***

I need to send 4 parameters through the post call to the `Cloudinary` service which I place in to a dictionary....

```
NSData *audioFile = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url];
NSMutableDictionary *myParam = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[myParam setValue:@(nowTime) forKey:@"timestamp"];
[myParam setValue:audioFile forKey:@"file"];
[myParam setValue:api_key forKey:@"api_key"];
[myParam setValue:finalSignature forKey:@"signature"];

[cloudManager setUpDataCall:@"/upload" withParameters:myParam];
```

The `setUpDataCall` goes to a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` with this code. This is the rest of the post URL if you were curious `@"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/karmo/raw"`

```
 - (void)setUpDataCall:(NSString *)callURL withParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters {

[self POST:callURL parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)  {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cloudManager:didReturnData:)]){

        //Success :)
    }

}failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cloudManager:didFailWithError:  )]) {

        //Error :(
    }
}];
}
```

***The Error***

I get this error when I try to send the file `Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)`.

When I add an exception breakpoint it identifies this

```
        [mutableRequest setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:self.writingOptions error:error]];
```

Which is in this method in the `AFURLRequestSerialization.m` class.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                           withParameters:(id)parameters
                                    error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

I have seen a few other stackoverflow questions like the one below but I am not sure if those are still relevant as the code from those posts seem to throw errors in the code as I am guessing `AFNetworking` has been updated since those posts.

[AFNetworking Uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234186/afnetworking-uploading-a-file)

Any code help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestions as explained in the following post's comments?
[Error with NSJSONSerialization - Invalid type in JSON write (Menu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893217/error-with-nsjsonserialization-invalid-type-in-json-write-menu#answer-9893370)